# Webpack for Cloudfront Functions

Tags: webpack, amazon-cloudfront

Has anyone used Webpack to manage their CloudFront functions?
I was using webpack to manage my Cloudfront Lambda@edge viewer request function but now I want to migrate it to a CloudFront function.

In an ideal world I would still use webpack so that I can have modularized code and testing but I have not been able to export my code in a format that works for cloudfront functions.

here is my index.js file

```
import { botDetection } from "./modules/bot-detection.mjs";

// Handler

function handler(event)  {
    var request = event.request;

    botDetection(request);

    return request;
}
```

and the bot detection module

```
export var botDetection = (request) => {
   var userAgent = request.headers['user-agent'];
   request.headers['x-bot'] = { value: isBot(userAgent) };
}

function isBot(userAgent) {
    if (!userAgent) {
        return true.toString();
    }
    var botTest = new RegExp('bot|crawler|spider|crawling|facebook|twitter|slack', 'i');
    return botTest.test(userAgent.value).toString();
}
```

and my package.json

```
{
  "name": "cloudfront-viewer-request",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "viewer-request Cloudfront Function",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/node": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1113.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "cookie": "^0.4.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-jest": "^27.5.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "lambda-tester": "^4.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.72.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
  },
  "esm": {
    "cjs": true,
    "mode": "all"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_OPTIONS='--experimental-vm-modules' jest",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "bail": true,
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageReporters": [
      "json-summary"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "coverage",
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "modules"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "cjs",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "ts"
    ]
  }
}
```

and finally my webpack config

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
  },
  experiments: {
      outputModule: true,
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using this webpack config and it output a webpacked file that worked perfectly in Cloudfront Functions

```
const path = require('path');
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "none",
  entry: './index.mjs',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true,
    chunkFormat: 'module',
    environment: {
        const: false,
    },
    iife: false
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
    layers: true
  },
  optimization: {
    concatenateModules: true,
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
            mangle : false
        }
    })],
  },
  target: 'es5'
};
```

Disabling mangle was particularly important as CloudFront is expecting to find a method called `handler`